# Search google with proxy

Tags: c#, search, bots

i am doing a small software that uses google search to display result for people in a desktop software.

User enter keyword and search results being displayed in a list box.
So far i don't have problem with that.

My actual problem is sometimes google blocks my ip address from searching and i have to wait for a certain amount of time then it will do the search normally.

By the way while google blocking my ip address in the software , i am still able to use google in the web browser , weird huh ?

Typically the error message i am getting is :

```
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

And here is the method i am using to search google :

```
    private string PROCESS_URL(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11";
        request1.Proxy = new WebProxy("xx.xx.xx.xx:xx"); // << my proxy address : port

        HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        string page_source1 = sr1.ReadToEnd();


        return page_source1;
    }
```

Any idea what should i consider ? maybe i need to send cookies along with the request ?
Am i missing some attribute ?

Well the idea here is to make google think i am a human not a bot

Comment: In the web proxy have you tried adding the protocol, http:// ?

Comment: I tried and also does not work.

Comment: If you omit that line completely, what happens?

Comment: It searches normally if i didn't use proxy but after a certain amount of time i get blocked too.

So actually google knows when i am using a proxy with bot.

Comment: an HTTP 503 error does not indicate a blocking of your IP.  I'd say either your proxy can't keep up, or some intermediary server can't keep up.